# aria-expanded="true" doesn't add class to parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add a class to my parent div when the collapse link has aria-expanded="true", but nothing is happening.

```
<div class="info-tab col-xl-3">
          <div class="info-img">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
          </div><!-- .news_img -->
          <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="info-title" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
            <?php the_title(); ?>
          </a>
        </div>
```

and the jquery

```
  jQuery(function($){
$(function() {
  $('.info-title[aria-expanded="true"]').closest('.info-tab').addClass('no-border');
});
});
```

i was also trying to get it work by changing the .info-title[aria-expanded="true"] to a[aria-expanded="true"] and closest to parents but it didn't work.

Comment: in OP the value is false

Comment: @guradio thank you for pointing that out for me.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a bootstrap collapse target witch by default has aria-expanded="false" and changes the value to true after clicking on it I needed to change my js code to:

```
jQuery(function($){
 $( ".info-title" ).click(function() {
  $( this ).closest('.info-tab').toggleClass('no-border');
 }); 
});
```

hope this helps someone in the future